# Java, pass-by-value, reference variables

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-value

I have a problem with understanding the "pass-by-value" action of Java in the following example:

```
public class Numbers {

    static int[] s_ccc = {7};
    static int[] t_ccc = {7};

    public static void calculate(int[] b, int[] c) {

        System.out.println("s_ccc[0] = " + s_ccc[0]); // 7
        System.out.println("t_ccc[0] = " + t_ccc[0]); // 7

        b[0] = b[0] + 9;  
        System.out.println("\nb[0] = " + b[0]); // 16

        c = b;
        System.out.println("c[0] = " + c[0] + "\n"); // 16
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        calculate(s_ccc, t_ccc);

        System.out.println("s_ccc[0] = " + s_ccc[0]);  // 16
        System.out.println("t_ccc[0] = " + t_ccc[0]);  // 7 
    }
}
```

I know that because s_ccc is a reference variable, when I give it to the method calculate() and I make some changes to its elements in the method, the changes remain even after I leave the method. I think that the same should be with t_ccc. It is again 
a reference variable, I give it to the method calculate(), and in the method I change the referece to t_ccc to be that of s_ccc. Now t_ccc should be a reference variable pointing to an array, which has one element of type int equals to 16.  But when the method calculate() is left, it seems that t_ccc points its old object. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the change remain for it, too? It is a reference variable after all.

Regards

Comment: Did you mean calculate(s_ccc, t_ccc) instead of calculate(s_ccc, s_ccc) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I do mean calculate(s_ccc, t_ccc). I am sorry.

Comment: @gemm: Could you amend your post please?

Answer (score 7):

There's an extended discussion of how Java passes variables at an earlier question "[Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)". Java really passes object references **by value**.

In your code, the references for the arrays (which are objects) are passed into `calculate()`. These references are passed by value, which means that any changes to the values of `b` and `c` are visible only within the method (they are really just a copy of `s_ccc` and `t_ccc`). That's why `t_ccc` in `main()` was never affected.

To reinforce this concept, some programmers declare the method parameters as `final` variables:

```
public static void calculate(final int[] b, final int[] c)
```

Now, the compiler won't even allow you to change the values of `b` or `c`. Of course, the downside of this is that you can no longer manipulate them conveniently within your method.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple way to understand it.

Java always passes copies of arguments. If the argument is a primitive type (e.g. an integer), then the called method gets a copy of the primitive value. If the argument is a reference type, then the called method gets a copy of the reference (**not** a copy of the thing referred to).

When your `main` method begins, each of `s_ccc` and `t_ccc` refers to a distinct array.
This is the situation, where parentheses indicate variables and square brackets indicate the actual array structures:

```
(s_ccc) ---> [7]
(t_ccc) ---> [7]
```

Assuming that you meant `calculate(s_ccc, t_ccc)`, then at the beginning of the `calculate` method:

```
(s_ccc) ---> [7]  <---(b)
(t_ccc) ---> [7]  <---(c)
```

Locals `b` and `c` are *copies* of globals `s_ccc` and `t_ccc` respectively.

Still within `calculcate`, after `b[0] = b[0] + 9` has completed:

```
(s_ccc) ---> [16] <---(b)
(t_ccc) ---> [7]  <---(c)
```

The zero (only) position *in the array referred to by `b`* has been modified.

The assignment `c = b` within `calculate` produces this situation:

```
(s_ccc) ---> [16] <---(b)
               ^------(c)
(t_ccc) ---> [7]
```

The local reference variable `c`, now contains the same reference as `b`. That has no effect on the global reference variable `t_ccc`, which still refers to the same array as before.

When `calculate` exits, its local variables (on the right-hand side of the diagrams) disappear. The global variables (on the left-hand side) were not used in `calculate`, so they are unaffected. The final situation is:

```
(s_ccc) ---> [16]
(t_ccc) ---> [7]
```

Neither `c_ccc` nor `t_ccc` were changed; each still refers to the same array as before `calculate`. Calling `calculate` changed the *content* of the array referenced by `s_ccc`, using a *copied reference* to that array (in `b`).

Local variable `c` started as a *copy of `t_ccc`* and was manipulated within `calculate`, but that changed neither `t_ccc` itself nor it's referenced data.

Answer (score 6):

The method receives variables by value. Those values can't be changed (as far as the caller of the method sees), but the values contained within them can (if it's an object, or as in this case, an array).

So when you change the value b[0] inside the array, the change can be seen outside the method. However the line

```
c = b;
```

will change the value of c inside the method, but that change will not be seen outside the method, since the value of c was passed by value.

Answer (score 5):

The line `calculate(s_ccc, s_ccc);` indicates you're not actually doing anything to t_ccc.
However, should this line have read `calculate(s_ccc, t_ccc);` than the effect remains the same.

This is due to the fact that you're assigning a new value to c here: `c = b;`
When assigning a new value to a reference argument the reference is lost.
This is the difference between altering a by reference variable and assigning a new value.

Answer (score 1):

On entry to `calculate()`, `b` points at `s_ccc` and `c` points at `t_ccc`.  Altering `b[0]` will therefore change `s_ccc`, as you've seen.

However, the assignment

```
c = b;
```

only points `c` at the same object `b` is pointing at, namely `s_ccc`. It does not copy the contents of what `b` points to to what `c` points to.  As a result, `t_ccc` is unchanged.  If you added the following line to the end of `calculate():`

```
c[0] = c[0] + 5;
```

`s_ccc[0]` would be 21.