# Object reference in java

Tags: java, object

consider this simple servlet sample:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    Cookie cookie = request.getCookie();
    // do weird stuff with cookie object
}
```

I always wonder.. if you modify the object `cookie`, is it by object or by reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "modify the object cookie"? Are you saying cookie = xxx, or are you actually changing the object itself e.g. cookie.setProperty(xxx)?

Comment: @allan, this is a poorly worded question.  "By value" or "By reference" are ways of passing parameters in a method call.  Those terms don't really apply when you're talking about modifying an object.  And I assume you mean "By Value" rather than "By Object".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> if you modify the object `cookie`, is it
>   by object or by reference?

Depends on what you mean by "modify" here. If you change the value of the reference, i.e. `cookie = someOtherObject`, then the original object itself isn't modified; it's just that you lost your reference to it. However, if you change the state of the object, e.g. by calling `cookie.setSomeProperty(otherValue)`, then you are of course modifying the object itself.

Take a look at these previous related questions for more information:

- [Java, pass-by-value, reference variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498747/java-pass-by-value-reference-variables)
- [Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Your statement "...then of course you are modifying the object itself" is misleading.  Of course you are modifying SOME object, but without the code/documentation for "getCookie()" you don't know if you're getting the actual cookie or just a copy of it.

Comment: It is the actual cookie; (there's actually no getCookie() method, but rather getCookies(), but we'll excuse that as a pseudocode shortcut). The documentation of getCookies() states "Returns an array containing all of the Cookie  objects the client sent with this request." with no mention of copying.

Comment: In any case, if it were a copy then we could have no expectation of being able to modify the original object, regardless of whether it was passed by value or by reference.

Comment: @jdigital: I agree and that is why I qualified my statement with "if you change the state of the object".

Comment: @Kieron: You're right, the object I was referring to is whatever was returned by "request.getCookie()".

Answer (score 3):

Java methods get passed an **object reference by value**. So if you change the reference itself, e.g.

```
cookie = new MySpecialCookie();
```

it will not be seen by the method caller. However when you operate on the reference to change the data the object contains:

```
cookie.setValue("foo");
```

then those changes will be visible to the caller.

Comment: You are assuming that getCookie() returns the actual object rather than a copy.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line of code

```
Cookie cookie = request.getCookie(); /* (1) */
```

the `request.getCookie()` method is passing a refrence to a `Cookie` object.

If you later on change `cookie by` doing something like

```
cookie = foo_bar(); /* (2) */
```

Then you are changing the internal refrence. It in no way affects your original `cookie` object in (1)

If however you change `cookie` by doing something like

```
cookie.setFoo( bar ); /* assuming setFoo changes an instance variable of cookie */
```

Then you are changing the original object recieved in (1)

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer.  There is no "request()"; "request" is an object.  The request.getCookie() returns a reference to a cookie object.

Answer (score 0):

object reference is different from object.
for eg:

```
class Shape
{
    int x = 200;
}

class Shape1
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Shape s = new Shape();   //creating object by using new operator
        System.out.println(s.x);
        Shape s1;                //creating object reference
        s1 = s;                  //assigning object to reference
        System.out.println(s1.x);
    }
}
```