# Does Java pass by reference?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Does Java really support passing by reference?

If it doesn't, why do we have the == operator for finding two objects with the same reference?

Comment: Call by reference and pass by reference are the same thing, right? If not, somebody can change the question back to what it was.

Answer (score 15):

Java uses pass by value, not by reference...

But, for non primitive types the value is the value of the reference.

So == compares the values of references for Objects.

Comment: But in byte-code level it has reference... right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode

Answer (score 4):

The point of distinction is between "pass**-by-**reference" and "pass**ing a** reference". You also sometimes see "call-by-..." and "pass-by-..." used interchangeably. For simplicity, I'll stick with "pass-by-...".

1. In academic, old-school, FORTRAN-relevant, comp-sci terminology, *pass-by-reference* means that the called code has access (reference) to a variable passed by the caller. Assigning to the formal parameter in the called code actually does an assignment to the caller's variable. The distinction is versus (among others) *pass-by-value*, which gives the called code a copy of the data (whatever it is) known to the caller.
2. In the contemporary Java-relevant, OO world, "having a reference" to an object means being able to get to the object itself. This is distinguished from "having a pointer" to emphasize (among other things) that one doesn't do "pointer arithmetic" on a reference. (In fact, a "reference" in this sense does not necessarily have to be an actual pointer-like memory address.)

Java passes arguments by value (in the first sense), but for object arguments, the value is a reference (in the second sense). Here's a bit of code that relies on the difference.

```
// called
public void munge(List<String> a0, List<String> a1) {
    List<String> foo = new List<String>(); foo.add("everybody");
    a0.set(0, "Goodbye");
    a1 = foo;
}

// caller
...
List<String> l0 = new List<String>(); l0.add("Hello");
List<String> l1 = new List<String>(); l1.add("world");
munge(l0, l1);
...
```

Upon return from `munge`, the caller's first list, `l0` will contain `"Goodbye"`. A reference to that list was passed to `munge`, which called a mutating method on that referred-to object. (In other words, `a0` received a *copy* of the value of `l0`, which was a *reference to* a string list that got modified.)

However, upon return from `munge`, the caller's second list, `l1` still contains `"world"` because no methods were called on the passed object reference (the value of `l1`, *passed by value* to `munge`). Instead, the argument variable `a1` got set to a new value (the local object reference also held in `foo`).

***IF*** Java had used pass-by-reference, then upon return, `l1` would have contained `"everybody"` because `a1` would have referred to the **variable** `l1` and not simply been initialized to a copy of its value. So the assignment to `a1` would have also been an assignment to `l1`.

This same issue was discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498747/java-pass-by-value-reference-variables/498895#498895), with ASCII-art to illustrate the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Java *does not* use pass-by-reference but rather pass-by-value. Primitive value parameters are **copied** to the stack, as well as pointers to objects.

The `==` operator should be used for comparing primitive values, and for comparing object references.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no. In Java there is only pass-by-value, and when you are working with objects (e.g. `Object obj = new Object();`), you are working with object references. Which get passed by value.

For details, see: [Parameter passing in Java](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html)