# In java are the parameters passed by reference or by value

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

In java are the parameters passed by reference or by value

Comment: And other duplicates or near-dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498747/java-pass-by-value-reference-variables  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589919/does-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: Are these preparing-for-interview questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is exactly one parameter passing
>   mode in Java -- pass by value -- and
>   that helps keep things simple.
>   -- James Gosling, "The Java Programming Language, Second Edition"
>   (James Gosling being the father of
>   Java)

Java is pass by value - always, for everything.

Answer (score 6):

All parameters in Java are passed by value. However, for reference types those values are references.

There are plenty of articles on this, including [this one](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) and [my own one](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/parameters.html).

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: by value, where the value is sometimes a reference.

Longer answer: Any primitive type will be simply passed by value. For non-primitives, you don't hold the object, but only a reference to it. This reference is passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Required reading on this subject (taken from javabot on irc://chat.freenode.net/##java):

http://javachannel.net/wiki/pmwiki.php/FAQ/PassingVariables

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm