# Server program in Java and passing a reference to a Socket object

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a multi-thread program in Java, where i am creating a seperate thread to handle each new client connection. I have:

```
Socket s;


while(true)
{
    s = server.accept();
    ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(s);
    Thread servingThread = new Thread(ch);
    servingThread.start();
}
```

In the ClientHandler thread i have:

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
{
    private Socket s;

public ClientHandler(Socket _Socket, boolean _accepted, BaseStation _bs)
{
    this.s = _Socket;
}
```

If in Java i can't pass an object but only a reference to it, isn't that going to cause a problem, to the `s` instance inside ClientHandler whenever `server` accepts a new connection?
Is it not going to change inside `ClientHandler` too and corrupt it? If so, what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is correct because the `Socket` object (like any other object in Java) is passed by reference, therefore there is a probability of it being referenced by different modules, or different threads, causing unpredictable behaviour.

However in case of your program there is no problem. The reason is: whenever server accepts a new connection it will create a *new* `Socket` object, which you are then passing to a *new* instance of `ClientHandler`. Therefore every new connection from the client will be served by an independent `ClientHandler` instance, so there are no race conditions to the `Socket` object to worry about. So you are safe for now.

As a counter-example if you decide to create two `ClientHandler` threads to read from the *same* `Socket` object like this ...

```
s = server.accept();
ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(s);
ClientHandler ch2 = new ClientHandler(s);
new Thread(ch).start();
new Thread(ch2).start();
```

... then you might be in trouble because two `ClientHandler`s will get the *same* reference to the *same* `Socket` object and if both attempt to read from the same socket they will each get only half of the data. E.g. if you are receiving a string `"hello"`, you might end up with `ch` reading `"hel"` and `ch2` reading `"lo"`, or any other combination.

Answer (score 2):

See [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) to explain.

Passing a new `Socket` instance to a new `ClientHandler` instance is fine because each `ClientHandler` has its own `Socket` - changes to the value of the local variable `s` do not impact copy of the `Socket` instance inside `ClientHandler`.

Something like *this* would cause a problem:

```
ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(s);
Thread servingThread = new Thread(ch);
servingThread.start();

s.someMethod(); // close, read etc.
```

Because `ch.s` and `s` both point to the same underlying `Socket` object instance.

BTW: spinning off a whole new Thread in a while loop is probably bad unless you're sure those threads will terminate.  Probably better to use a ThreadPool.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing, but your code should work as shown.  Java first passes by value, and then by reference.  I.E., you're not passing in a pointer to your "`Socket s`", but the actual value of "`s`" at the time you're passing it.

To simplify things and eliminate confusion, I'd just remove your forward declaration of "`Socket s;`" and make your first line in the loop "`Socket s = server.accept();`".

Comment: normalocity - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589919/does-java-pass-by-reference , http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html , and others confirm that Java does first pass by value.

Comment: Exactly, Java passes first by value, then by reference.  :-)

Comment: We could force a pass-by-reference by passing a "container" which gets resolved by value, maintaining the value as the actual reference.  I.E., Socket[] socketHolder = new Socket[1]; socketHolder[0] = s.  If the OP then used socketHolder[0] for everything instead of simply "s", then he really would be passing the socket by reference, and would have problems.

Comment: So, um. I'm going to take a big, fat, slice of humble pie here. I get it. You're correct. I've removed my answer and comments. Wow, I really got on fire there. I also removed my down vote. My apologies - I see the difference now. We can safely delete this comment thread, since it's no longer relevant.

Comment: normalocity - no problem, apologies accepted!  I'm glad to see people get so passionate about the language now and then.  :-)