# Variable scope with a method in Java

Tags: java

I thought I understood variable scope until I came across this bit of code:

```
private static void someMethod(int i, Account a) {
  i++;
  a.deposit(5);
  a = new Account(80);
}

int score = 10;
Account account = new Account(100);
someMethod(score, account);
System.out.println(score); // prints 10
System.out.println(account.balance); // prints 105!!!
```

EDIT: I understand why a=new Account(80) would not do anything but I'm confused about a.deposit(5) actually working since a is just a copy of the original Account being passed in...

Comment: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `a` is *a copy of the reference being passed in*, so it still has the same value and refers to the same `Account` object as the `account` variable (that is, until you reassign `a`).  When you make the deposit, you're still working with a reference to the original object that is still referred to in the outer scope.

Answer (score 3):

It might be time for you to read more about [pass-by-value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498747/java-pass-by-value-reference-variables).

Answer (score -2):

In java, variables are passed by value.

Comment: I think you should remove this, since objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @stacker - how can that be? Just the answer before says it is pass by value.